# Parity invariance of Dirac action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, parity

The Dirac action is
$$S=\int d^4 x \mathcal{L}(x)$$
where the $\mathcal{L}(x)$ is the Lagrangian density given by
$$\mathcal{L}(x)=\bar{\psi}(x)(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi(x).$$

In proving the parity invariance of the Dirac action, is it appropriate to ignore the tranformation  properties of the Dirac spinors $\psi(x)$, and just do a transformation $\mathcal{L}(x)\rightarrow\mathcal{L}(x')=\mathcal{L}(x^0,-\vec{x})$, and use

$$S=\int d^4x\mathcal{L}(x)=\int d^4x'\mathcal{L}(x')$$
to prove the invariance?

In other words, just treat the Lagrangian density as a function and do a coordinate transformation on it.

Comment: What does your favourite QFT text book say about this?

Comment: Are you sure the action is invariant under the transformation you suggest?